# Storing the set variable value of one macro inside a set variable outside the macro in which it is defined

Tags: apache, velocity

I have the following macro that sets a variable with a string .How can i use this value inside another macro's set variable?Where somename="Outpatient"

```
#macro(deepak $somename)
    #set($somename1=$somename) 
    #end
```

Answer (score 0):

If this macro is called at any point in your template, before the second macro wants to use that variable, it should still be available. So simply

```
#set $var = $somename1
```

should work. Or simply use directly $somename1 of course.

From velocity [user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html):

> Once a value has been assigned to a variable, you can reference the variable anywhere in your HTML document.